# What Standing does a Default Defendant have?

Tags: united-states, federal-courts

Does a default defendant have standing to argue anything other than removal of the default and the dollar amount of damages?
Can a default defendant argue the validity or anything else about any pleadings in a case?

Comment: When you say a "default defendant" do you mean a defendant who was ruled against by default (meaning they didn't show up to court, so the court awarded the prosecution)?

Comment: hello and thanks.
I did not mention CIVIL LAWSUITS.
There are two defaults; Default aka Clerk's Entry of Default.  which plaintiff obtains when the defendant does not timely answer the lawsuit aka summons and complaint.  The other default is a Default Judgment.  That is were the judge reviews the facts for clear abuse and rules on the dollar amount of the damages.  Supposedly the default defendant is barred from questioning the facts of the case but is allowed to argue over the plaintiff's requested dollar award.

Comment: My question is for those with experience in this area.  If the default defendant is only allowed to motion for a withdrawal of the default and question the dollar award; where can one find this in writing?